# Overriding CSS table styles to remove padding

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've tried several options to do this, but none have worked. Just trying to remove the padding around the images and tighten up the table. I'm thinking there must be some inline style I can use, but I'm too much of a novice to figure this out just yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html generated from photoshop.

```
<table id="Table_01" class=" alignleft" style="height: 291px" border="0" width="570" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.boem.gov/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/BOEM-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.boem.gov/" width="297" height="115" border="0" /></a></td>
<td colspan="2"><a href="http://www.jasco.com/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/JASCO-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.jasco.com/" width="273" height="115" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.csaocean.com/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/CSA-Ocean-Sciences-Inc.-Logo.jpg" alt="https://www.csaocean.com/" width="152" height="96" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.ifaw.org/united-states"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/IFAW-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.ifaw.org/united-states" width="145" height="96" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.mbari.org/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/MBARI-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.mbari.org/" width="125" height="96" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://schmidtocean.org/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/Schmidt-Ocean-Institute-Logo.jpg" alt="https://schmidtocean.org/" width="148" height="96" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.teledynemarine.com/SitePages/HomePage.aspx"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/Teledyne-Marine-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.teledynemarine.com/SitePages/HomePage.aspx" width="152" height="80" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://oceansonics.com/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/Ocean-Sonics-Logo.png" alt="http://oceansonics.com/" width="145" height="80" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.l-3mps.com/maripro/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/L3-Maripro-Logo.jpg" alt="http://www.l-3mps.com/maripro/" width="125" height="80" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://sea-birdscientific.com/"> <img src="http://oceanleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/Sea-Bird-Scientific-Logo.png" alt="https://sea-birdscientific.com/" width="148" height="80" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

Comment: there is no padding, its the images actual `width` and `height` which have white space around

Comment: _Photoshop_ generated that? It's atrocious. `border= width= cellspacing= cellpadding=` on tables are obsolete; same with `width= height= border=` on **`img`** tags...  all of these things should now be done in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Using an inline style isn't a great idea, but including the attribute style='padding: 0px, margin: 0px' inline in your img tags would ensure the browser isn't rendering any extra space around the images themselves. A better option would be to include a .css file with the rule:
td img {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px
}

That rule should automatically assign the styling to all img tags within your table.

Answer (score 0):

Its Problem with Image I removed your style still its having white space its because of your images.
You can see below
your code
`<table id="Table_01" class=" alignleft" style="height: 291px" border="0" width="570" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

I removed this style and tried here
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iR1X96?p=preview)